# Appium scroll until not find element

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I found code to scroll until finding the element,

```
WebElement el = driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator
("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0))
.scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+text+"\").instance(0))");
el.click();
```

How do I modify that code to scroll until the element does not contain the specific text?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it is in python but self explanatory -

```
def scroll_element_into_view_android(list_element, search_text):

    element = driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator(
        'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"' + list_element + '\")).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"' + search_text + '\").instance(0));')
    return element
```